# Windows 10 network mapping using server name in hosts file

Tags: windows, samba, network-share, windows-10

I want to map a samba shared folder on my Windows 10 Home PC. 
The server is a Linux - CentOS 7 with Samba 4.4.4.
If I use the server IP address then it works fine however if I create an entry in the hosts file to name my server then I got path not found error.

First with simple net view this works:

```
net view \\192.168.0.10
```

I added the following to my hosts file:

```
192.168.0.10 myserver
```

But got the following result:

```
net view \\myserver

System error 53 has occurred.
The network path was not found.
```

Pinging the server works fine using myserver

**UPDATE**

Using the IP I can access the server and the Get-SMBConnection result is:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-SMBConnection

ServerName   ShareName UserName               Credential              Dialect NumOpens
----------   --------- --------               ----------              ------- --------
192.168.0.20 IPC$      DEVELOPER-PC-01\vilma DEVELOPER-PC-01\unixmen 3.1.1   1
```

Using the server name I can not even browse the server.

Comment: What version of SMB are you using? Open a SMB connection with the server than use the PowerShell 'Get-SMBConnection' cmdlet.

Comment: Samba 4.4.4 is running on the CentOS box.

Comment: But what's its negotiated connection from the windows box

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure what you mean. I don't really know how to open a SMB connection.

Comment: On the Windows machine either map a network drive or browse via UNC to the server in Explorer. While that's open, open an elevated PowerShell console and run the 'Get-SMBConnection' cmdlet.

Comment: Original post updated with the result.

Answer (score 0):

Disable strict name checking on the server:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
Value name: DisableStrictNameChecking
Data type:  REG_DWORD
Value:      1
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the server is a Linux (CentOS) server. Updated my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. 
If I add the server names to the **lmhosts** file instead of **hosts** file then it works fine.